# New documentation format for TYPO3 extensions

Tags: documentation, typo3

I heard something about a new documentation format for extensions, but I can't find any info about that on typo3.org.
We currently want to write a manual, so should we still use Libre Office?

Comment: There is a newer question with more up-to-date answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384225/howto-add-documentation-to-typo3-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This answer is outdated. The supported formats are now reST and Markdown. Please see [newer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47717545/2444812) in a similar question.

Yes, please use the [doc_template](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/doc_template/current/) Open/LibreOffice file for the moment. The migration to reST is in progress, but there's no rendering on typo3.org, yet.

You could manually place a PDF version into the doc/ folder of your extension, as this is a bit nicer to read than with LibreOffice (personal opinion).